# Difference between protractor locators

Tags: protractor

I was going through the protractor guide here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-protractor

It says in order to locate a element, I could use

```
var temp = element(by.css("someclass"));

or alternatively

var temp1 = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('someclass'))
```

Which kind of locator is to be used when ? Could someone pls clarify

Answer (score 5):

They are the same. `element` is the preferred syntax because it is shorter and because you can chain locators and use some fancy protractor features. Protractor extends the webdriver api and that is why you can use the same functions that you would use in plain webdriver.

For example, the following expressions are equivalent:

```
ptor.findElement(by.css('.foo')).getText()

element(by.css('.foo')).getText()

$('.foo').getText()
```

To look for multiple elements use:

```
ptor.findElements(by.css('.foo'))

element.all(by.css('.foo'))

$$('.foo')
```

There are many examples in the api.md document:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementfinderprototypeelement

Comment: Andres.. this doesn't seem to be the case .. take a look at this link https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1008#issuecomment-47707081

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `ptor.findElement` and `element` is that the first should be used pages *without* Angular while the second is used on pages *with* Angular. This is related to how protractor [syncs with Angular](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1008). The first returns a WebDriver `WebElement`, the second returns a Protractor `ElementFinder`.

However to address your question directly, there is *no difference* between the locators returned by `by.css` and `protractor.By.css`.
The two are **equivalent**. The object referenced by the global `by` object is the same as the the object referenced by `protractor.By`.

From Protractor's [runner.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ddb8584a59343284904676ef6d8db5c1c996b900/lib/runner.js#L161):

```
global.by = global.By = protractor.By;
```

There are two versions of the API. The old version used `protractor.By`, whereas the new version uses `by`. You may often see the old style but if you are in doubt, you can use the new style and be sure nothing unexpected will happen.